# Why am I having difficulty scrolling via href="element"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a button that toggles a div to show / hide using a `.hidden` class to `display:none` and `visibility:hidden`.
But for some reason, when I anchor said button, it does not scroll down to the hidden class? And in this case, the button won't anchor to anything at all?

```
<a href="#anchor" class="btn" onclick="return false;">Button</a>
```

anchoring to

```
<div id="anchor" class="hidden">Stuff</div>
```

and jQuery is simply:

```
$(".btn").click(function() {     
    $("#anchor").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Well it's not gonna scroll with `onclick="return false;"` there.

Comment: The idea is to scroll down to the element as it shows.

And the onclick prevents it from doing the default of loading the homepage.

Comment: An `href` that starts with `#` is not going to reload the page.

Comment: It essentially doesn't, but there's a click event somewhere that goes to the homepage (this isn't on a homepage). Is there a way to override the onclick="return false" so that it would anchor normally?

Comment: Unfortunately not. onclick="return false" literally means don't do what you are supposed to do. In fact, it prevents the click event of the element.

Comment: So, I'd essentially have to stop the default behavior.. I see. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `onclick="return false;"` from your element - this is preventing default behavior

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/L268mm89/) - working demo

---

Alternatively - if you need to prevent the default behavior because of some weirdness going on per your comments - you could always manually scroll to it. Here is an animation driven approach with an optional time in ms to finish...

```
$('.btn').click(function(e) {  

    e.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#anchor').offset().top
    }, 200);
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/jzqduvtr/) - alternative demo

Lastly - for the "no frills" approach - the following should suffice ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView))...

```
$('#anchor').get(0).scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: Super helpful, second answer helped override the base href which was the issue for the homepage load by default. Thanks again!